# Is Buffz(TM) Affected by +Item Effect?

Tags: penny-arcade-4

In Penny Arcade on the Rainslick Precipice of Doom 4, there is an item you can use called Buffz (TM) that grants bonus stats to a "character" in battle.  There are also passive abilities, one active ability (Eat Quarter -- Vendorr), and some items that grant bonus "Item Effect".

Is Buffz (TM) affected by +Item Effect?  If so, how did you determine this?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, if you use the character Vendorr in battle, he has an ability called "Eat Quarter" which increases the effects of items. If a Buffz is used by him, then the effect is increased-similar to how you can upgrade it in a store.

Buffz base stats increase is 20%. Subsequent upgrades raise it to 30% and then 40%. I believe that by using Eat Quarter, you get the next level of upgrade. For example, if you have no upgrades and you use a Buffz with Eat Quarter, that character would get a 30% stats increase.

I never used Vendorr in my playthrough, but I highly suggest the use of Buffz.

Comment: It is just a difficult thing to test.  Do you have any ideas as to how to test this?

Comment: Save the game. Run a battle and see how much damage a character's regular attack does. Do it again with a single use of Buffz (not with Eat Quarter) and do some attacks. Do it again but with Eat Quarter and compare. My guess is the damage should increase each run. I found Vendorr to be a bad character and sooner stick with others and just spend a turn using Buffz